# React Native MySQL User Registration

Tags: react-native, user-registration

I am doing the user registration for my mobile app using React Native, MySQL.
I am able to get the data from the database but I cant post the data of the new user to database.
I encountered this issue. Anyone has this before?

[Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBJeZ.png)